# ios - How to hidden YTPlayerView Youtube logo

Tags: ios, objective-c, ytplayerview

One day, the YouTube logo appears like a picture.
Vanish together when disappears.
Touch the image to reappear.
If you touch the logo, there is a problem with YouTube.
I want to hide the logo.
We looked at the parameter at the youtube developer site.
It is useless to apply a variable called modestbranding.
I want to hide the logo.

It's my code

```
NSDictionary *dicPlayerVars = @{@"autohide":@1,
                                @"playsinline":@1,
                                @"showinfo":@0,
                                @"rel":@0,
                                @"color":@"white",
                                @"modestbranding":@1,};

[self.viewVideo loadWithVideoId:strVideoId playerVars:dicPlayerVars];
```

[image]

Comment: show your tried code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**modestbranding**

> This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar.

You can add `?modestbranding=1` to your url. That will remove the logo.

You can find other options on the [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) website.

Comment: Added modestbranding to my code.
It's my code.

NSDictionary *dicPlayerVars = @{@"autohide":@1,
                                        @"playsinline":@1,
                                        @"showinfo":@0,
                                        @"rel":@0,
                                        @"color":@"white",
                                        @"modestbranding":@1,};

[self.viewVideo loadWithVideoId:strVideoId playerVars:dicPlayerVars];

Comment: @J.soo - change `@"showinfo":@0,` as  `@"showinfo":@1,`

Comment: @J.soo - for sample see this https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/135

Comment: @J.soo - if you are using both `@"showinfo":@0,@"modestbranding":@1,` will not work,

Comment: Thank you !! I understand the cause of the problem. :)

Comment: @J.soo - happy to hear, its the problem in google also , use `@"showinfo":@1,@"modestbranding":@1,` , surely works